# Play 2.0 IOException

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've just installed play-2.0 and keep getting the following error when I try run any of the sample apps:

```
IOException: Cannot run program "javac": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've tried on ubuntu 11.10 installing play via the typesafe stack and on crunchbang 10 by downloading the zip from the website. Both times I get the same error?

What am I missing?

Comment: Which Java package do you have installed - Sun, OpenJDK, IcedTea, etc.? And do you have the JDK installed (required for `javac`) or just the runtime (JRE)?

Comment: $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: for windows 64 bit OS users (specifically win 7) be sure to install the 32 bit jdk.  I had previously only installed the 64 bit jdk and ran into the error above.  Once the 32 bit JDK was installed the framework rendered the HTML page as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the primary requirement for Play 2.0 is JDK 6 or later, according to [the framework's documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Installing).

Then, you also need to ensure that `javac` can be found within the current path. I got the same error as you before I added the directory containing `javac` to path.

Comment: Thanks, it seems there was some thing wrong with my jdk install. The javac command wasn't in my path, even though I had java installed. Had to reinstall it, using: sudo apt-get install default-jdk and that sorted everything.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. I was added JAVA PATH and JAVA_HOME AND PLAY to path. javac and java commands are working fine from terminal. But still problem was not solved.

**It is solved after creating symbolic soft links java and javac in /usr/bin.**

Comment: I ran into the same problem when running Play 2.2 on IntelliJ, although javac is working fine in a terminal. Thanks for sharing, it was  fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem. The solution was to install the **32-bit** version of JDK

Comment: I ran into the same problem using Windows 8 and by uninstalling and install 32 bit version of JDK and also setting path to bin folder solved my problem.